# Reloading iframe from separate iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent, reload

I have checked all the reload iframe from another iframe posts on stackoverflow...and I have tried all their solutions but it doesn't seem to help me! So my problem is that I have two iframes on the same page. The iframe's sources are php files that interact with each other, however I need the iframes to reload that way the changes are shown. I have tried many different ways (which I will list below). These iframes are from the same domain. Maybe it is something else that is messing this up? Thanks in advance.

Different statements called from inside one iframe:

```
parent.document.getElementById(id).src = parent.document.getElementById(id).src;
parent.getElementById(id).location.reload();
```

Trying to call a parent function that works in the parent window:

Inside iframe -

```
parent.refresh(id);
```

Parent window working function -

```
function refresh(id) {
document.getElementById(id).src = document.getElementById(id).src;
}
```

Comment: Are both iframes sent from same domain as your php script? You can not alter other domain iframes.

Comment: Yes they are. Sorry I forgot to include that.

Comment: What happens if you run refresh("idString") manually ftom console after first iframe finishes?

Comment: Also, is there any chance the iframes are nested? As in one iframe inside the other?

Comment: the refresh(id) works and refreshes the iframe when it is ran from parent window but not when it is run from the child iframe.

Comment: Can you post the markup showing the `iframe` elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you assign `name` to `iframe` most browsers will let you access the `iframe`'s `window` object via the `name` value. This is different from referring to an `iframe` by its `id` property which will give you a reference to the `iframe` element itself (from its owner `document`), and not the `iframe`'s content `window`.

Simple Example: (from the parent document)

```
<iframe name='iframe1Name' id='iframe1Id'></iframe>
<script>
    // option 1: get a reference to the iframe element:
    var iframeElem = document.getElementById('iframe1Id');

    // update the element's src:
    iframeElem.src = "page.html";

    // option 2: get a reference to the iframe's window object:
    var iframeWindow = window.iframe1Name;    

    // update the iframe's location:
    iframeWindow.location.href = "page.html";
</script>
```

**Let's review your code:**

```
parent.document.getElementById(id).src = parent.document.getElementById(id).src;
```

This works if executed from within the `iframe`, provided you use the correct `id`. You may want to use a debugger to verify that `parent.document.getElementById(id)` returns a reference to the correct element, and check your console to see if any exceptions are being thrown (try hitting F12). Since you didn't post your full code (including markup) there's no way I can to think of to tell what the issue is here.

Debugging tips:

- check `parent.location.href` to make sure you are accessing the window you think you are,
- check `parent.document.getElementId(id)` to make sure that you get an element object (as opposed to `null` or `undefined`),
- check `parent.document.getElementById(id).tagName` to make sure you are using the correct ID (`tagName` should === "IFRAME")

**This line:**

```
parent.getElementById(id).location.reload();
```

has two problems:

1. `getElementById()` is a function of `document`, but it is being called from `parent` which is a `window` object, and
2. `location` is a property of a `window` object. You are trying to access the `iframe` element's `location` property, which does not exist. You need a reference to the `iframe`'s `window`, not its element.

**Besides the `name` method, there are other ways to get the `iframe`'s window object:**

1. `document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow; // for supported browsers`
2. `window.frames["iframeName"]; // assumes name property was set on the iframe`
3. `window.frames[i]; // where i is the ordinal for the frame`

If changing the `src` of the `iframe` element is not working for you, these other fixes might:

`parent.document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.location.reload();`

or

`parent.frames["yourIframeName"].location.reload(); // requires iframe name attribute`

or

`parent.frames[0].location.reload(); // frames of immediate parent window`

or

`top.frames[0].location.reload(); // frames of top-most parent window`

Caution: If using the `name` method be careful not to use a common value for `name`, like "home", for example, as it conflicts with a FireFox function called `home()` and so Firefox will not automatically create a reference to an iframe's window if it is named `home`. The most reliable method is probably to use `window.frames[]` as I believe that has been around for a long time (works in FF / Chrome / Safari / IE6+ (at least))

**A more in-depth (but pretty minimal) example follows, tested in Chrome, FF, and IE:**

File #1: frametest.html (the parent window)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="frame1Id" name="frame1Name" src="frame1.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frame2Id" name="frame2Name" src="frame2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

File #2: frame1.html (frame 1's src)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
FRAME 1
<script>
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="#ccc";
    setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="#fff";},100);
    document.write(new Date());
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="parent.document.getElementById('frame2Id').src=parent.document.getElementById('frame2Id').src;" value="Refresh frame 2 by ID"/>
<input type="button" onclick="parent.frame2Name.location.reload();" value="Refresh frame 2 by Name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

File #3: frame2.html (frame 2's src)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
FRAME 1
<script>
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="#ccc";
    setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="#fff";},100);
    document.write(new Date());
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="parent.document.getElementById('frame1Id').src=parent.document.getElementById('frame1Id').src;" value="Refresh frame 2 by ID"/>
<input type="button" onclick="parent.frame1Name.location.reload();" value="Refresh frame 2 by Name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This example demonstrates how to define and manipulate `iframe`s by `id` and by `name`, and how to affect one `iframe` from within a different `iframe`. Depending on browser settings, origin policy may apply, but you already said that your content was all from the same domain so you should be OK there.

Comment: This was definitely a very resourceful post! It helped me with my problem and I learned quite a bit from it. Thank you :)